# what is preferred approach to return business validation results in business layer

Tags: java, validation, exception, jakarta-ee, business-logic

Let's assume we have a client application (either web or standalone) which uses kind of business layer (EJB, Spring services etc). Let's say user wants to execute some business logic (e.g. create something). This operation has some preconditions like data format, existing of other objects in DB, permissions etc. Now what is the best design of this business logic layer, I mean how to return validation errors, indicate success, return unexpected error etc?

Ways I know:

1)

for validation errors return e.g. OperationResult object having status and list of violations,

for success: OperationResult with status=success and empty errors list,

for unexpected errors throw runtime exception

2)

for validation errors throw ValidationException (runitme or checked?) having list of violations

for success: void or created entity if required

for unexpected errors throw runtime exception

There are two basic ways I know but every time I start writing I have hard time to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I have an aversion for the validation exception method, after all there is nothing exceptional in a validation error, so I find it hard to justify to use an exception for that. So on a theoretical basis the only valid option is the first one.

Having said that, although it depends on what validation framework you're using*, but it's usually much easier to code the exception version.

Whether your validation exception (if you're using one) should be checked or not opens up another can of worms, some people are very much against checked exceptions in general, others will say the exact opposite. For my two pennies worth I believe that runtime exceptions should be reserved for coding errors and an "expected" exception should be checked, whenever that's possible. But I have to stress that this is just personal preference on my behalf.

*If you have multiple validators that will all have to be run in a validation phase, exceptions are not very effective. If you intend to stop at the first failed validation step, exceptions are easier to implement and probably more readable.

Comment: I agree. Best to make a list of validation errors, then throw the exception at the very end (if the list is not empty). Attach the list to the exception. Lists also allow you to have "warnings" for display to the user, so you can have an extra parameter for acknowledging warnings and proceeding anyway...

Comment: @Ben, if so, should ValidationException be checked or runtime? If checked, user is required to handle that and it can sometime mess up in his code a lot (too many try/catch blocks). Wouldn't be better to explicitely return kind of status object having list of violations as in 1) version?

Comment: On the other hand having flexible ValidationException hierarchy would be better on client side (catch and handle each the right way) than simple list of violations.

Comment: @bottle As you pointed out, unlike a result object an exception forces the client to act on it. Whether that's a good thing can be debated but I think it is. If the client has too many try-catch blocks, it should probably be reorganised to handle and display validation error in a common way. But then if you already have a module to handle all errors, you don't need to have an exception anymore. :)